# How to sort thumbnails from a collection other low size photos?

Tags: windows, python, jpeg, thumbnails

I have a collection of low sized photos (low file size, say around 50KB), consisting of thumbnail images of my camera photos, whatsapp forwarded images and other images downloaded from internet. The thumbnails all are of varying dimensions. Is there any way with which I can separate out the thumbnail images from this collection? This is because, I have lost my original photos beyond recovery and the thumbnails are only now left for me, for reliving the old memories.
Any help much appreciated!

Is there any unique file metadata/ something added while a thumbnail is created so that it could be distinguishable from others? (like something in the exif header, for example)

Comment: Will size not help you? In Windows use search term "size:<40kb" for example.

Comment: If on Android, I believe there are apps which "recover" deleted images which actually just retrieve image thumbnails. Maybe you could start there.

Comment: @DanielK All the files are around that size only.. So I doubt if that works..

Comment: @Xertz The files were deleted from a pendrive.. Any hope?